# PLSS second division starting point vs Legal State plane coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cogo, state-plane, plss

Why do I have my starting point off by 33 feet from the center of section 25 as shown in the image "A"?

"B" is my starting point and "C" is the true starting point as found on my legal description instructions. My data frame properties and my data layers are all in the same state plane coordinate system- StatePlane California V.

[image: Starting point off by 30 feet]

Comment: I've seen basemap imagery off that much before. Do you have anything you can check the linework with, like recorded survey monuments?

Comment: Where is that section corner, Latitude and Longitude? You can check it with some data from [BLM CA Cadastral PLSS](https://data.doi.gov/dataset/blm-ca-cadastral-plss-standardized-data-cadastralreference-version-1-0-cadnsdi)